# Make objects drawn using x3dom.js immovable

Tags: x3dom

By default objects in x3dom are movable and rotatable. Can we disable these two functionalities while retaining zoom functionality of the objects? Actually I'm trying to plot bar chart with 3d effect and zoom functionality enabled. Any links would be really helpful.

Thanks,
Kishan.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can control the way the X3D scene allows a user to interact with it by setting properties via the `<NavigationInfo>` element. You will want to set the `explorationMode` attribute in this case. See X3DOM's documentation for the `<NavigationInfo>` element [here](http://doc.x3dom.org/author/Navigation/NavigationInfo.html).

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the objects are not moved or rotated when you change the viewpoint in the scene. You are moving the "camera" location.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.